# how to design the asp.net page to support all multiple screen resolutions?

Tags: html, layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to design asp page to support in all multiple screen resolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883155/how-to-design-asp-page-to-support-in-all-multiple-screen-resolutions)

hi ,

my system has 1280×1024 screen resolution.in my system my developed design is looking good.but
in other systems like 1024×768 screen  resolution systems my design is vary it's looking too badly.

i did n't know how to acheive this .pls clarify this..........

Comment: With 30 questions asked, it would be **REALLY GREAT** if you'd accept a few answers.

Comment: also, don't post the same question twice

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with ASP.Net, You need to design your pages with width/height with percentage and not pixel. You can also start with some of the free templates available on net to get the idea to design html pages with resolution independent.

some free resolution independent templates:
http://www.templateworld.com/free_templates.html

Comment: you don't have to do it with percentages.  There are lots of fixed-width designs on the web and for some things that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

[asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) is the wrong tag here, this is a layout issue. You can either choose to use [liquid/fluid layouts](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/), or you set a base resolution for the "lowest common denominator" when it comes to your clients viewing your site. Right now it's still 1024x768.

<sub>I personally don't think anyone is still "really" using 800x600, and if they are, I don't support them</sub>

Comment: why don't you retag this question?  I need two more votes or I'd do it.